# JQuery is not working in php while loop

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to use JQuery autocomplete function for a editable table. My table has multiple rows(the count is variable). I am using while loop to get the data from the database, My JQuery function is placed outside the loop. But the autocomplete operation is working only for the first row.

Is there any suggestion to call the function in every row? I want the autocomplete operation to happen in every row.

Please suggest me as I am very new to this.

Here is my code

```
            <?php
            $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "A", "ABC");
            $output = '';
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM PROVISIONING WHERE COMMENTS='NOT_UPDATED' AND UPDATED_BY='NOT_UPDATED' ORDER BY id DESC";
            $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
            $output .= '
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script>
            $( function() {
                var availableTags = [
                    "Arindam",
                "Completed",
                "Pending"
                                        ];
                $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
                });
                $( "#tags1" ).autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
                });
                $( "#tags2" ).autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
                });
                $( "#tags3" ).autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
                });

            } );
            </script>
            <div class="ui-widget">
            <table align="middle" border="1" bordercolor="green" class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
            <th style="color:blue;font-style:italic;" hidden>Id</th>
            <th style="color:blue;font-style:italic;">Task ID</th>
            <th style="color:blue;font-style:italic;">Request ID</th>
            <th style="color:blue;font-style:italic;">END Date</th>
            <th style="color:blue;font-style:italic;">Updated Date</th>
            <th style="color:blue;font-style:italic;">Pending Tasks</th>
            <th style="color:blue;font-style:italic;">Comments</th>
            <th style="color:blue;font-style:italic;">Assignee</th>
            <th style="color:blue;font-style:italic;">Updated By</th>
            <th style="color:blue;font-style:italic;" hidden>Delete</th>
            </tr>';

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
            {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
            $output .= '
            <tr>
            <td hidden>'.$row["id"].'</td>
            <td class="TASK_ID" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'" >'.$row["TASK_ID"].'</td>
            <td class="REQUEST_ID" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" >'.$row["REQUEST_ID"].'</td>
            <td class="END_DATE" data-id3="'.$row["id"].'" >'.$row["END_DATE"].'</td>
            <td class="UPDATED_DATE" data-id4="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["UPDATED_DATE"].'</td>
            <td id="tags" class="AUTOMATED_TASKS" data-id5="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["AUTOMATED_TASKS"].'</td>
            <td id="tags1" class="COMMENTS" data-id6="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["COMMENTS"].'</td>
            <td id="tags2" class="ASSIGNEE" data-id7="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["ASSIGNEE"].'</td>
            <td id="tags3" class="UPDATED_BY" data-id8="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["UPDATED_BY"].'</td>
            <td hidden><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-id9="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">x</button></td>
            </tr>';
            }
            $output .= '
            <tr>
            <td id="TASK_ID" contenteditable></td>
            <td id="REQUEST_ID" contenteditable></td>
            <td id="END_DATE" contenteditable></td>
            <td id="UPDATED_DATE" contenteditable></td>
            <td id="AUTOMATED_TASKS" contenteditable></td>
            <td id="COMMENTS" contenteditable></td>
            <td id="ASSIGNEE" contenteditable></td>
            <td id="UPDATED_BY" contenteditable></td>
            <td hidden><button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">+</button></td>
            </tr>';
            }
            else
            {
            $output .= '<tr>
            <td colspan="4">Data not Found</td>
            </tr>';
            }
            $output .= '</table>
            </div>';
            echo $output;
            ?>
```

Comment: Where is your code? We need to see the code to help you :-)

Comment: You got more down vote, because you are not share your code.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I am pretty new in stackoverflow. Please find the code

Comment: Look at your developer console and check for errors via php and the (incomplete) mysql query. Here are a few links http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php then come back and tell us if there are any.

Comment: my code is working for the 1st row, so I guess the query is a complete one, the jquery function is not working in while loop

Answer (score 0):

ID must be unique across the whole page.

If you generate multiple rows in your table, you'll have a cell with `id="tags"` in each row (i.e. not unique within the page). JQuery won't be able to find the other cells due to this.

If you want more cells to share something you can find with JQuery's selector, use `class` attribute instead of `id` and `.tags` instead of `#tags`.